# Using mingw and msys to convert VC++ libraries into mingw libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, interop, mingw

Are there any guides on how to convert/use VC++ libraries with the MinGW toolchain?

Comment: Just to clarify: It seems that "how to compile freeglut for MinGW" is answered at the links you have given. Is your question simply "how to convert vc++ libraries to MinGW libraries?". That is, is the whole OpenGL/Freeglut scenario just an example and not part of the question?

Comment: yes just an example. sorry I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### C interface

If the library binary interface is exposed as a C only interface, and is provided as a .dll you can use the VC-library in a mingw-compiled program without any conversions (I don't know if VC .lib files are compatible with the mingw toolchain).

### C++ Interface

If there is no C-level interface, you need the source code of the library, since you must compile the library with g++. The reason for this is that there is no common ABI¹ between g++ and VC.

## ¹ABI

The ABI (application binary interface) defines the technical low-level details of C++. It handles how names are mangled, how functions are called, how the exception system works and many other stuff. The ABI is not defined by the C++ standard, so (almost) every compiler vendor created its own. Those ABIs are not interchangeable, so you can't mix binaries (.o/.obj and .a/.lib files) produced by different compilers. In fact the situation is that worse, that you even can't reliable interchange binaries created by different versions of one compiler, or created with the same compiler, but with different compiler options(like one binary with, the other without exception handling).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the MinGW folks have a [FAQ page about this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers).

Short answer: not really.

Long answer: For DLLs, maybe.